# Why can't I 'get' my rosrun parameters?

Tags: ros, param-server, parameter, getparam, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node that should be able to run other nodes. It has a basic method of doing so using

```
system("rosrun myproject Robot robotname:='Botty'");
```

This should set the parameter robotname to 'Botty'. In my Robot node file, I have this code that should retrieve that parameter:

```
std::string robotname;
n.getParam("robotname", robotname);
ROS_INFO(robotname.c_str());
```

However, nothing is printed. When I execute `rosparam list`, the corresponding parameter is `/RobotNode1/robotname`. What am I doing wrong? I think that `rosparam list` output might be a good hint - is there a way to set that parameter when executing rosrun without referencing `RobotNode1`?

[edit] n is a NodeHandle.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189916/why-can%27t-i-%27get%27-my-rosrun-parameters?/) by [falseazure](https://answers.ros.org/users/19907/falseazure/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2014-08-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-13**:
Note that `robotname:='Botty'` does not set `/RobotNode1/robotname`, but just `/robotname`. Use `_robotname:=Botty` for parameters in the node's namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`/RobotNode1/robotname` means that this parameter has been set in the private namespace of the node.

So, you have to create a private node handle to retrieve this parameter. Do this:

```
ros::NodeHandle private_node_handle("~");
```

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [falseazure](https://answers.ros.org/users/19907/falseazure/) on 2014-08-13**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [db](https://answers.ros.org/users/31437/db/) on 2019-05-23**:
I just spent several hours trying to get the parameter fetching to work, because someone thought it was a good idea to use this private and public parameter setting thing.